# How do I find how much it costs to park a B747 at an airbridge in Perth?

Tags: landing-fees

I need to park my B747 at Perth for 1 hour. How much will it cost me? You may assume I have 200 fare paying passengers. I must use an airbridge for those 60 minutes.

To be honest, I don't really own a B747 (yet), but am having trouble figuring out the costs for this. I've found some example costs for various airports around the world, and some landing fee documents on the airport's site, but they're a trifle confusing to decipher.

Perth's commercial fees appear to be [here](https://www.perthairport.com.au/-/media/Files/CORPORATE/Work-with-us/Airport-charges/NON-PSA-Aero-Charges-Schedule-01-JUL-2016.pdf).

Comment: Related: [How do airports charge airlines for using their gates?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13813/1696)

Comment: Starting an airline? That's interesting! Need pilots? Drop me a message!

Comment: Outside of a Japanese domestic shuttle, one hour is a pretty fast turn around for a B747.

Answer (score 8):

Note that parking is not the same as waiting at the gate to load/offload passengers. Parking is when your aircraft is not using the terminal, but the airport facilities (like aprons, hangars, etc.)

Let us assume you are carrying 200 passengers, and leaving with 200 passengers:

First of all, you have to pay the landing fee, which is:

(4.891 x 400) + (9.528 x your landing weight, in tonnes)

Next, you have to calculate the terminal charges - assuming you are an international flight, (so you are using Terminal 1):

(13.868 x 400) + (0.450 x 200) + (1.111 x 200) + (5.997 x 200)

- 13.868 is the terminal fee, per arriving or departing passenger
- 0.450 is Common Use Service charge, per departing passenger
- 1.111 is the security fee, per departing passenger
- 5.997 is the baggage checking fee, per departing passenger

Since you'll only be staying for 1 hour, you don't have to pay any parking charges; which are only charged for staying more than 2 hours.

So total *passenger fees* are: AUS $9,015.20, before tax;  you still have to calculate your landing weight and multiply it by 9.528 to get the final amount.

Comment: Is it possible there's a decimal point in the wrong place? I can't see any airline managing to make a profit with costs of AUS$20k per passenger.

Comment: Ah, you have a point. Maybe in AUS the `.` is not a thousands separator?

Comment: Terminal charges are $13.868 is just under $14 per passenger. Total passenger fees will come to ~$9k not ~$9M.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid In English, the thousands separator is a comma; the decimal separator is the period.

Comment: Can you share a source for where these numbers came from?

Comment: @fooot Those figures come from the link in the question which links to a PDF from the Perth Airports Corporation website.